# How to fix Magento extensions that are not compatible with RWD theme?

Tags: magento

Take for example "Brand / Product Logo Slider by AheadGeeks" extension will work fine in default theme, but in RWD theme which I used for default will not work.

What should I do?

Comment: can you describe in detail what will not work?

Comment: Some Magento Extensions like for example this one "Brand / Product Logo Slider by AheadGeeks". This will work and would display if I change to default theme in Magento. But the one I'm customizing is the RWD theme in Magento 1.9. The slider will not show.

Comment: the rwd theme inherits from basic theme. if a module install his layout files in default you have to copy it to rwd manually.

Comment: wow, i'm going to check that out. will give you update on it. thanks Kevin.

Comment: Yeah it works Kevin, the one you said. It solves the problem.